# Implementing estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath: causes the tableView to scroll down while reloading

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I've implemented 'infinite scrolling' on one of my projects and I was playing around with the new `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method. Once I implemented that delegate method, my tableView jumps (a.k.a scroll to the bottom) whenever i call reloadData (which happens when i add a new set of rows.)

Without that method, my tableView stays in place and it adds the additional rows to the bottom of the tableView without any scrolling.

I'm calling the `[tableView reloadData]` and not the other methods (`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:`). I don't call the beginUpdates or endUpdates since I'm reloading the whole table.

Has anyone experienced this ? I

Comment: without add and values to array You can't  scroll tableView more.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you. Let's say I had 10 items in the array initially and each item is a row in the tableView, as soon as the user scrolls down to the 8th item, I add another set of items so my array count is 20 now with 20 rows for the tableView. If the user continues to stay on row 8 and I call reloadData, it jumps down to the 11th item (when estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath: is implemented).

Comment: Did you ever really fix the problem? I am having the same issue and I'd prefer the tableview not to jump at all... :)

Comment: @Georg I was able to reduce the jumping by returning better estimates for the cell heights. See my original reply: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22927535/852376

Comment: @newDeveloper but it's still jumping, right? I'd expect no jump at all :)
I'd rather not show the scroll indicator (even though that is bad, I know) but the jumping is even worse...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So here's what i did to reduce the jumping while reloading the tableView.

In the `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` I started returning a better estimated height. The more accurate the height is, lesser the jumping while adding new rows to the bottom.

I also started caching the calculated height of the cell from `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` in a dictionary and return the cached value the next time it calls the `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Hope this helps anyone who encounters this issue.

Comment: much better, but not totally

Comment: This COMPLETELY fixed my problem. In `willDisplayCell`, I took the value of the rendered cell and stored it in an array. When `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` is called, it returns the cached value. The values will always be accurate because `willDisplayCell` is always called. And even if they aren't they will be off my pixels at most. CHEERS! This was causing me a huge headache.

Answer (score 2):

I filed a BugReport quite a while ago (16472265) and today got the response that it's fixed in iOS8. Tried it out and it works now as expected. No more jumping of the tableview! Wohoooo

Answer (score 0):

Check your condition  in this scrollView Delagete method,

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

Comment: again I think I'm lost here. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. I'm aware that a tableView implements UIScrollViewDelegate and it probably calls this method when the reloadData occurs (my guess is that it calls scrollViewDidScroll: first) are you suggesting that I should forcefully make the tableView not scroll (by setting the contentOffset to the previous value) ? It seems like a workaround rather than a proper fix.